# Can Response.OnStarting be used with async await?

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to to use the `Response.OnStarting` to execute some code which leverages the async await pattern.  The `Response.OnStarting` method is defined as

```
 public void OnStarting(Func<Task> callback)
```

And I often see it used to modify headers via code like the following:

```
 context.Response.OnStarting( () => {
      //modify the headers or do some synchronous work
 });
```

However I need to do some async work from the OnStarting delegate.  Let's say the method performing the async work is declared as follows:

```
 public Task DoWorkAsync() {

        //write to a db or do something else async

        return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
```

Is it valid to call this method from via an OnStarting delegate using the following approach?

```
  context.Response.OnStarting(async () => {
       await DoWorkAsync();
  });
```

In Visual Studio this compiles without warnings and it appears to work.  However it seems odd to me that the `Response.OnStarting` method could be used to make both synchronous and async calls.  Sometimes the async await world still gets me scratching my head a bit.  Can you throw light on whether this approach works and why?  And why it is that `Response.OnStarting` can be used with a sync and async anonymous method (if in fact it can)?

**Update**
I did some digging to see if I could find the code that gets calls the delegate passed to the `OnStarting` method.

What I found was that the `DefaultHttpRespose` object contains the `OnStarting` method and inside that method it basically calls the `IHttpResponseFeature.OnStarting`, see here:

```
 public override void OnStarting(Func<object, Task> callback, object state)
    {
        if (callback == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));
        }

        HttpResponseFeature.OnStarting(callback, state);
    }
```

[link to source code](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/DefaultHttpResponse.cs#L99)

But interestingly, the only place I can find an implementation of `IHttpResponseFeature.OnStarting` is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/07d115400e4f8c7a66ba239f230805f03a14ee3d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/OwinFeatureCollection.cs#L158) with this code:

```
 void IHttpResponseFeature.OnStarting(Func<object, Task> callback, object state)
    {
        var register = Prop<Action<Action<object>, object>>(OwinConstants.CommonKeys.OnSendingHeaders);
        if (register == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(OwinConstants.CommonKeys.OnSendingHeaders);
        }

        // Need to block on the callback since we can't change the OWIN signature to be async
        register(s => callback(s).GetAwaiter().GetResult(), state);
    }
```

But that implementation blocks on the async delegate call.  There is even a comment to that effect but I don't understand why that was necessary?  And I'm not sure this is the implementation of `IHttpResponseFeature.OnStarting` that is getting ran, it's just the only one I could find on github.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the definition takes a `Func<Task>`  then it looks like it was meant to support both sync and async work. The docs don't seem to mention anything that would indicate otherwise. If you dig a little deeper there's probably a `async void Starting(...)` event handler awaiting the callback, but I haven't looked that far.

Comment: I don't know. This is interesting.  I may have found the code that calls the OnStarting delegate but it just raises more questions.  I'll update my question to include those findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However it seems odd to me that the Response.OnStarting method could be used to make both synchronous and async calls.

Synchronous APIs *must* be implemented synchronously. A `Func<int>` *must* return an `int`; it cannot return a `Task<int>` instead.

Asynchronous APIs may be implemented asynchronously *or* synchronously. A `Func<Task<int>>` may have an asynchronous implementation, returning a `Task<int>` that will complete in the future. Or it may have a synchronous implementation, returning a `Task<int>` that is already completed with an `int` value.

When dealing with asynchronous APIs (including interfaces and delegate signatures), synchronous implementations are entirely permissible.

I wouldn't be distracted by the blocking implementation. The comment indicates that OWIN has a synchronous API in a place where there *should* be an asynchronous API, and `IHttpResponseFeature.OnStarting` is just hiding that oddity from you.

Comment: Stephen, thank you for that.  Your explanation makes sense to me but the part I still don't understand is that  when specifying the `OnStarting` `delegate` it appears that it's OK to use the `async` keyword or to omit it.  ie.  `context.Response.OnStarting( async () => { await someMethod();  });`  or `context.Response.OnStarting( () => {  });`. Perhaps I'm not fully understanding the `async` keyword.  How can one method signature both allow the `async` keyword to be used and allow it to be omitted?  Shouldn't it always be required even if doing sync work and returning a `Task.CompletedTask`  ?

Comment: @RonC: `async` is an implementation detail; it's not part of the signature. The `OnStarting` method takes a `Func<Task>` delegate, i.e., a method that returns a `Task`. You can return a `Task` any way you want - either implicitly (e.g., `async`) or explicitly (e.g., `Task.CompletedTask`).

Comment: Light bulb went on for me.  That helps my understanding enormously.  Thank you.